# PHP cooldown set in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, time, timer

I have this php code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['last_submit']) && ((time() - $_SESSION['last_submit']) < 120)) {

  $timecounter =  time() - 120 - $_SESSION['last_submit'];

  output("Still on cooldown! Wait: (".$timecounter. "-) more seconds!");

} else { 

  $_SESSION['last_submit'] = time();

}
```

And what I basicly want is, I want to link it to mysql database, I want to be able to submit, have a "cooldown" of 2 minutes stored in the database, and whenever the cooldown in the database in 0, the cooldown is off, and the code can be executed again, with setting a 2 minute cooldown etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: using a database to keep track of "cooldown" wouldn't be very smart, as it will only check everytime someone visits the PHP page. it would make more sense to just schedule a cron job

Comment: Why is that? I mean, Can't I just link the cooldown to the user table I made, even if people are logged out, the timer keeps going?

Comment: a PHP page doesn't run forever, only when it is visited. in other words, if noone visits the PHP page, it will not check the timer, and thus whatever code that needs to be executed will not be executed.

Comment: I know but the timer runs in the database, and the php code is only to check the timer

Comment: yes, but if no one visits the php page, how is the timer going to be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT next_submit FROM cooldown");

if ($res->num_rows == 0){
    $next_submit = time()-60;
} else {
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $next_submit = $row['next_submit'];
} 

if ($next_submit < time()){
    $next_submit = time() + 2*60;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE cooldown SET next_submit='$next_submit'");

    // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats what you have but it would require you to currently refresh the page to see when the timer is up. Do you want a live update? Is that want you are asking for?

If you want it from your database just store the value using an update statement when they click 'submit' and then do the same thing you have just replace the `$_SESSION['last_submit'];` with the var you get the databse value to be.